# disable selected option from select using vue

Tags: vue.js

i have this select and i want to make it so that when I press any of the options, the option i pressed gets disabled so the user can see the option he selected easier.

```
<select v-model="modalIU.inpIdSpecialitate" v-on:change="disableEnable()">
    <option :value='null'>.:: fără legătură specialitate ::.</option>
    <option v-for="item in allSectiiSpecialitati.filter(el => el.idSpecialitate !== null).sort((a, b) => (a.denumireSpecialitate > b.denumireSpecialitate) ? 1 : -1)"  :value="item.idSpecialitate">@{{ item.denumireSpecialitate }}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to add a custom method, you can work with `v-model` and the data you already have.
Add a `:disabled='modalIU.inpIdSpecialitate === item.inpIdSpecialitate'` on the option with the v-for, so you conditionally disable the option if it is the one currently selected.
You can then remove the `v-on:change="disableEnable()"`. Also consider adding a `:key` attribute to your v-for for best practice.

Comment: tried adding the :disabled attribute but that didn't do it. any ideas as to why it might not work?

Comment: That's weird, I tried it in on localhost before submitting my answer and it was working, the option was disabled correctly when clicked

Answer (score 1):

I just created a codesandbox example for this functionality, I added a `disabled` property for each option, and on `change` event listner, I get the option index, and make it disabled.

https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-smoke-lwcriw?file=/src/components/DisabledOptionOnSelect.vue:351-513

Comment: the code has errors for me. could you change the link?

Comment: I just fixed the error, please check again.

Comment: I think you have to little tweak the code, Instead of disable all the options one by one on click, You have to only disabled the clicked one and enable all others.

Comment: I thought the desired behavior is to disable each option selected, and leave it disabled.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal, I just updated it to behave as you mentioned.